# Wi-Fi syncing and Home Sharing with iPhone 5 not working in iTunes after iOS 8 upgrade

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, wifi, ios

I have a recent MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks). I also have an iPhone 5 that had iOS 7.1, but I recently updated it to iOS 8.

When I had iOS 7, I used to be able to connect via Wi-Fi and drag music from my Mac to my iPhone. All I had to do was let both of them automatically connect to my home Wi-Fi and drag the songs to my phone, which was listed in the "Devices" section of the sidebar in iTunes.

But now, I don't see my phone in the sidebar. I can still transfer the songs via USB, but I can't do it via Wi-Fi.

**Does anyone know why this is happening or what can be done about it?**

I clicked "Sync Now" in the "iTunes Wi-Fi Sync" section in the Settings app on my iPhone, and it looked like it did something, but I don't see the iPhone in the iTunes sidebar. I looked at "Devices" in the file menu in iTunes and I don't see my iPhone there like I used to.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that Home Sharing is not working. It is enabled in iTunes, but on my iPhone, I don't see the "Libraries" choice in the "More" section in the Music app. I tried looking for something that would appear to let me access the music on my laptop from my iPhone, as I have been doing with iOS 7, without any success.

Comment: assume you are on the same WiFi network?

Comment: Yes, I am on the same WiFi network, just as I was with iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my iPhone by simultaneously holding down the home button and the power button for about 5 seconds, then waiting for it to restart. Now, everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your Iphone connected to a charger before it will be possible to sync over WiFi

From the [iOS 8 User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf):

> If Wi-Fi syncing is turned on, iPhone syncs when it’s connected to a power source, both iPhone and your computer are on and connected to the same wireless network, and iTunes is open on your computer.

EDIT: Update to iOS 8.0.1 and it is working again without connected to a power source.

Comment: Really? I could swear that I was able to sync before without it connected to a charger. In any case, it is plugged in right now and I don't see it in the sidebar.

Comment: How can I update to iOS 8.0.1? I went to "Settings", "General", and "Software Update", and it is telling me "iOS 8.0. Your software is up to date.".

Comment: You shold be able to update from iTunes too - if OTA doesn't work.

Comment: Apple has - for now - removed the iOS 8.0.1 update: http://www.macrumors.com/2014/09/24/ios-8-0-1-issues-possible-fix/

Comment: I connected my iPhone via USB and clicked on it in the sidebar in iTunes. It told me I am running iOS 8.0. I clicked "Check for Update" and it told me "This version of the iPhone software (8.0) is the current version.".

Comment: iOS 8.0.2 is now online, so this update should fix your problem with WiFi sync.

Comment: My problem is already fixed. I think I'll update to 8.0.2 if they go for more than a day or 2 without pulling it.